# Bash script exiting after 1st non-zero result even though -e is not set in ENV

Tags: bash, exit

Every system I have used in the past continues my simple bash scripts if one line returns a non-zero result. Some new Ubuntu LTS 14.x systems now exit on the first failure. I used

```
echo $-
```

and e does not appear in the list. What else should I be looking for?

Added from comment:

```
$ declare -f command_not_found_handle
command_not_found_handle ()
{
    if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
        /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1";
        return $?;
    else
        if [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
            /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1";
            return $?;
        else
            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2;
            return 127;
        fi;
    fi
}
```

Comment: Does `declare -f command_not_found_handle` output anything?

Comment: Yes, the result is as expected I believe

`command_not_found_handle () 
{ 
    if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
        /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1";
        return $?;
    else
        if [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
            /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1";
            return $?;
        else
            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2;
            return 127;
        fi;
    fi
}`

Comment: So your script will exit if you attempt to use any command that cannot be found where either of those scripts returns non-zero or when neither of those scripts can be found. What exit code is your script exiting with? At what point in the script? What does `set -x` show you?

Comment: You can also look at whether there's an ERR trap set. That should show up in `set -x`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "in ENV", by the way. The `-e` flag isn't part of the environment.

Comment: That is weird.  Does your interactive shell has the same problem? For example, run 'false' command, and see if it exits your shell. BTW, could you post the so-called 'simple shell script' that is forced to exit on the first non-zero result?

Comment: Can anyone reproduce this? I can't with Ubuntu 14.04.2 and Bash 4.3.11. My technique was to try "#!/bin/bash" vs. "#!/bin/bash -e" as the first line of a script. One case exits on failure, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Use a bash **trap** in your script, see the example below of a bash script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

main() {
    trap 'error_handler ${LINENO} $?' ERR
    ###### put your commands in the following
    echo "START"

    non_existent_command

    echo "END"
}

error_handler() {
    process="$0"
    lastline="$1"
    lasterr="$2"
    printf 'ERROR: %s: line %s: last command exit status: %s \n' "$process" "$lastline" "$lasterr"
    trap - ERR
    exit 0
}

main
```

if you try to launch a non existent command (`non_existent_command` in the example) or a command with exit status different from 0 the trap will activate the `error_handler` function which contains the exit command `exit 0`.
In the sample above the output will be:

```
>START
>./new.sh: line 8: non_existent_command: command not found
>ERROR: ./new.sh: line 8: last command exit status: 127
```

Note that "START" is printed but "END" not.